# Sending mails from Unix to Outlook or other Email account

Tags: sendmail

All,

I want to send a mail from Unix OS (without GUI) to MS Outlook or other email account (gmail,yahoo etc). Please help.

Thanks
Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the common way

```
$ uuencode file file | mailx -s "subject" myaccount@gmail.com
```